# how to create database in mongodb using MongoVUE tool

Tags: mongodb, database

I have to create the database as name "personal_connections" using mongoVUE tool.

but i am getting application error message as below

> "Database name must contain alphanumeric charachers only, please correct it and retry"

Do you have any idea about it ..could i not create database with "_" chars for my application ?

thanks for your reply in advance.

Javaamtho

Comment: In latest version mongovue(0.9.7.2) bug with 'underscore' was fixed for collections, but still not for database names.

Answer (score 2):

According to the error message, yes, you cannot have an _ in your database name.

This could be a restriction/bug of the tool, though. I cannot find documentation about this being prohibited by MongoDB itself. The [mailing list says](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/b320346f50a9dc78):

> Database names:
>
> - empty string is not valid
> - cannot contain space, ".", "$", "/", "\" or "\0"
> - should be all lowercase
> - limited to 64 bytes (after conversion to UTF-8)
> - admin, local and config are reserved
>
> Collection names:
>
> - empty string is not valid
> - cannot contain "\0"
> - avoid creating any collections with "system." prefix
> - user created collections should not contain "$" in the name
>
> Also, the sum of the database name + collection name + 1 is limited to
>   121 bytes (in practice stay below 100).

Comment: the document for MongoVUE may be limitation but finally i am able to create database using the special char"_".  **I CREATE PROPER NAME DATABASE AND THAN LATER, I CHANGED IT NAME FROM FILE SYSTEM ..C:/DATA/ FOLDER ..THIS LOCATION IS STORE MONGO ALL DATABASE.**

Comment: @javaamtho: I'd be careful with that. If your system obviously has issues with underscores in the name, I'd rather not brute-force my way around that. Who knows what else might break. I cannot imagine a compelling reason why you cannot choose another database name.

Comment: the issue with not my system but the tool(MongoVUE) used to create mongo db, and after done this ..i had testing lots my application and its look well yet :), i could not change the another database name as we follow that naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

Underscore issue will be fixed in next release of [mongovue](http://www.mongovue.com/)(current version is *0.9.7.2*). It is mongovue author comment from [facebook mongovue page](http://www.facebook.com/#!/pages/MongoVUE/111527225578623):

> Underscores in database names has
>   already been fixed. Will be available
>   in the next release. Thanks!